# Challenging plot: model selection

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need a hand with this! I know it is very tough and challenging. But with you, geniuses, we will make it!

[image]

**MWE with horizontal hierarchy:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=right,level distance=1.25in,sibling distance=.25in]
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style= 
            {thick, draw, edge from parent fork right},
         every tree node/.style=
            {draw,minimum width=1in,text width=1in,align=center}}
\Tree 
    [. Data 
        [.{Training data}
                [.{Training Data } ]
            [.{Training Labels } ]
            [.{Test data } ]
            [.{Test Labels } ]
        ]
        [.Training data
                [.{Hyperparameters values } ]
            [.{Hyperparameters values } ]
            [.{Hyperparameters values } ]
        ] 
        [. Best hyperparameters values ]
        [. Learning Algorithm ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Each of the subdiagrams is straightforward with `forest` and Ti*k*Z. Just produce them one by one and put them in a table, where the first column are the numbers. The challenge here is IMHO not conceptual but just being patient enough to do these subdiagrams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may know, I am not very excited about typing in the texts from a screen shot. So I created the first three sub diagrams. The second one was fun because I could try out something moderately new when making the arrows terminate at the boundary of the ellipse. All other things are pretty much standard (in the sense that there are tons of posts of that sort). For the sub trees I use `forest`, and the big thingy is IMHO a table, not a tree. The use of `\savebox`es is not really necessary here but will be needed if you want to use a `tikzpicture` instead of a table. And I stop after diagram 3, otherwise it takes too much time and is too much repetition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shapes.misc,shapes.multipart,intersections}
\newsavebox\boxA
\newsavebox\boxB
\newsavebox\boxC
\newsavebox\boxD
\newsavebox\boxE
\tikzset{2box/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw,minimum
width=#1},2box/.default=8em,
every picture/.append style={font=\sffamily,
every text node part/.style={align=center},
every pin edge/.style={-stealth}},
chess/.style={minimum size=#1,draw,fill=gray!20,path picture={
\foreach \XX in {0,...,4}
{\ifnum\XX>0
\draw ($(path picture bounding box.north west)+\XX*(#1/5,0)$) 
-- ($(path picture bounding box.south west)+\XX*(#1/5,0)$)
($(path picture bounding box.north west)+\XX*(0,-#1/5)$) 
-- ($(path picture bounding box.north east)+\XX*(0,-#1/5)$);
\fi
\draw[fill=blue!50] ($(path picture bounding box.north west)+\XX*(#1/5,-#1/5)$)
rectangle ++(#1/5,-#1/5); }
}},chess/.default=1.5cm,rr/.style={rounded rectangle,draw,align=center},
2ell/.style={ellipse split,draw}}
\sbox\boxA{\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={grow'=0,edge={-stealth},l sep=4em}
[{Data\nodepart{two}Labels},2box=10em
 [{Training Data\nodepart{two}Training  Labels},2box,fill=gray!20]
 [{Test Data\nodepart{two}Test Labels},2box=6em,fill=green!20]
]
\end{forest}}
\sbox\boxB{\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={grow'=0,edge={-stealth},l sep=3em,s sep=0.3em,
where level=1{rr,anchor=center,l sep+=4em}{},
where level=2{chess,no edge,pin={[node font=\small]right:Performance}}{},
}
[{Training Data\nodepart{two}Training  Labels},2box,fill=gray!20,anchor=text
split east
 [Hyperparameters\\ value
  [{},alias=ml31]
  ]
 [Hyperparameters\\ value,alias=ml22
  [{},alias=ml32]
  ]
 [Hyperparameters\\ value
  [{},alias=ml33]
 ]
]
\path let \p1=($(ml31.north)-(ml33.south)$) in (ml22) -- (ml32) 
    node[name path=elli,midway,ellipse,draw,node font=\bfseries,align=center,
    minimum height=\y1,inner xsep=-1ex]{Learning\\
    Algorithm};
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\path[name path=l\X] (ml3\X.west-|ml22.east) -- (ml3\X.west);
\path[name intersections={of=elli and l\X,sort by=l\X}]
\ifnum\X=1
(ml3\X.west-|ml22.east) edge[-stealth] (intersection-2)
(intersection-1) edge[-stealth] (ml3\X.west)
\else
(ml3\X.west-|ml22.east) edge[-stealth] (intersection-1)
(intersection-2) edge[-stealth] (ml3\X.west)
\fi;}   
\end{forest}}
\sbox\boxC{\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=0,edge={-stealth},l sep=4em}
[{Training Data\nodepart{two}Training  Labels},2box,fill=gray!20,anchor=text
split east
 [{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
 \textbf{Best}\\ hyperparameters\\ values\\[-0.3ex]~
\end{tabular}\nodepart{lower}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}~\\[-0.3ex]\textbf{Learning} \\\textbf{Algorithm}\end{tabular}},
 2ell,anchor=center,inner ysep=-1.8ex
  [Model,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,fill,text=white,anchor=center]
 ] 
]
\end{forest}}
\newcommand{\BC}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(X.base)}]
\node[circle,fill,text=white,minimum size=1.3em,#1](X){#2};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{cp{1em}l}
\BC{1} & & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\boxA}}}\\[4em]
\BC{2} & & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\boxB}}}\\[5em]
\BC{3} & & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\boxC}}}\\
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! The last arrow is not straight. I will try to draw step 4, which is tricky :)

Comment: @Delan You're right. I added the missing `anchor=center` to fix it.