# Plot with polygons, ellipses, squares and rectangles

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you help me finish this?

[image]

MWE:

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{grimsel/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split parts=1,draw,
        fill=gray!20,blur shadow,rounded corners,align=center}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0mm,minimum height=1cm,outer sep=3mm,scale=0.8,>=Latex,font=\sffamily\footnotesize,
  indication/.style={minimum height=0cm,outer sep=0mm},
  oneblock/.style={transform shape,minimum width=1cm,draw,thick},
  fullset/.style={transform shape,minimum width=10cm,draw,thick}]


    \begin{scope}[xshift=15cm,scale=0.5,local bounding box=rightside box]
    \foreach \x in {0,1}
    {
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,4}
        {
            \draw (\x*11,0) +(0,-\y*2) node[fullset,anchor=west] {};
            \draw (\x*11,0) +(\x*5+\y,-\y*2) node[oneblock,draw,anchor=west,fill=blue!50] {};
        }
    }
    \coordinate (R) at (rightside box.west);

    # Polygon
    [Model,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,fill,text=white,anchor=center]
    \end{scope}



  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some things that I just copied from [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507796/194703), one moderately new thing, and things that I just didn't do because they are too standard (i.e. boring). The copied things are in the lower left part of the picture, and presumably others would be more eager to help if you collected those yourself, and you would also enjoy it more if you just tried out. The moderately new thing is the matrix of `board`s. (It could be made fully automatic using the the count `\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn` but harder to understand/customize.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,shapes.geometric,shapes.multipart,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[board/.style={minimum width=5em,minimum height=1em,
 draw,fill=gray!20,path picture={
 \foreach \XX in {0,...,5}
 {\ifnum\XX>0
 \draw ([xshift=\XX*1em]path picture bounding box.north west)
 -- ([xshift=\XX*1em]path picture bounding box.south west);
 \fi
 \ifnum\XX=#1
 \draw[fill=blue!50] ([xshift=\XX*1em]path picture bounding box.north west)
 rectangle ([xshift=\XX*1em-1em]path picture bounding box.south west); 
 \fi}
 },pin={[name=pin-#1]right:Performance$_{#1}$},scale=1.2},
 box/.style={draw,minimum size=1.2em,fill=blue!50,label={[node
 font=\tiny,align=center]#1}},
 2box/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw,minimum
 width=#1}, 2ell/.style={ellipse split,draw},
 every pin edge/.style={-stealth},font=\sffamily] 
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,nodes={anchor=center},
   row sep=1ex,column sep=1em,inner xsep=0.3em] (m) { 
   1\textsuperscript{st} & |[board=1]| \\
   2\textsuperscript{nd} & |[board=2]| \\ 
   3\textsuperscript{rd} & |[board=3]| \\
   4\textsuperscript{th} & |[board=4]| \\
   5\textsuperscript{th} & |[board=5]| \\
 };
 \draw[semithick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=1pt}] (m-1-2.north east)
   -- ++ (-4.8em,0)
  node[midway,above=1ex,align=center] (TF) {Training\\ Fold};
 \node[left=1em of TF,align=center] (VF) {Validation\\ Fold};
 \node[anchor=south,rotate=90] at (m.west){$k$ iterations};
 \draw (VF) -- ([xshift=0.6em]m-1-2.north west);
 \draw[semithick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=1pt}] (m-5-2.south west) -- ++ (4.8em,0)
  coordinate[midway,below=1ex](5f);
 \draw[semithick,decorate,decoration={brace,raise=1pt}] (m.north east) 
  -- (m.south east)  node[midway,right=1ex,2box=4em,draw=none,anchor=text west,
  rectangle split part align={left}]{Performance
 \nodepart{two}$=\sum\limits_{i=1}^5\textsf{Performance}_i$};
 \node[below=2em of m-5-2.south west,2box,fill=gray!20] (2box) {Training Fold
  Data\nodepart{two}Training Fold Labels};
 \node[below=2em of 2box,2ell,inner ysep=-0.2ex] (2ell){\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  Hyperparameters\\ values
  \end{tabular}\nodepart{lower}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textbf{Learning} \\\textbf{Algorithm}\end{tabular}};
 \node[below=2em of 2ell,regular polygon,regular polygon
  sides=6,fill,text=white] (6gon) {Model};
 \draw[>=stealth]  (5f) edge[->] (2box) (2box) edge[->] (2ell) (2ell) edge[->]
 (6gon); 
 %
 \draw[semithick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=1pt}] 
 (pin-5.south west) -- (pin-5.south east) coordinate[midway,below=1.2ex] (pf)
  node[midway,below=2em,box=left:{Validation\\ Fold Data}](b1){};
 \node[right=4em of b1,box=above:Prediction,yshift=-0.5ex] (b2){};
 \node[below=4em of b2,box=below:{Validation\\ Fold Labels}] (b3){};
 \path (b2) -- (b3) coordinate[midway,right=1em] (aux)
  node[right=1em of aux] (PF) {Performance};
 \draw[-stealth] (b2.east) -| (aux) |- (b3.east) (aux) -- (PF);
 \node[below=0.1em of b1,regular polygon,regular polygon
  sides=6,fill,text=white] (6gon2) {Model};
 \path coordinate[left=1em of b2] (aux2); 
 \draw[-stealth] (6gon2.east) -| (aux2) |- (b1.east) (aux2) -- (b2);
 \draw[-stealth] (pf) -- (b1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cat! Thank you so much, I really appreciate it! Would you mind finish the “C” part? Which has like a “feedback loop”. If it is so hard, please, guide me and I will try to do it

Comment: * I meant: "would you mind finishing"

Comment: @Delan I added the stuff but it is IMHO really just repetition. You will really enjoy things much more if you try yourself. Every answer here has a certain author, certain preferences, a certain style, and none is perfect. You will be much more satisfied if you develop your own style.

Comment: I agree! The thing is sometimes I do not have that much time. I have to spend the whole day at work and then I got home and I continue with my thesis and Tex and I do my best. Thank you very much, I really appreciate your words and work.