# Feedback loop with polygon

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you help me finish step 4 from this plot? I am using code from my previous post (**All credits to Schrödinger's Cat**): [Schrödinger's cat Code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507796/194319)

I think I should have to add this chunk of code:

```
\draw[semithick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=1pt}] 
 (pin-5.south west) -- (pin-5.south east) coordinate[midway,below=1.2ex] (pf)
  node[midway,below=2em,box=left:{Validation\\ Fold Data}](b1){};
 \node[right=4em of b1,box=above:Prediction,yshift=-0.5ex] (b2){};
 \node[below=4em of b2,box=below:{Validation\\ Fold Labels}] (b3){};
 \path (b2) -- (b3) coordinate[midway,right=1em] (aux)
  node[right=1em of aux] (PF) {Performance};
 \draw[-stealth] (b2.east) -| (aux) |- (b3.east) (aux) -- (PF);
 \node[below=0.1em of b1,regular polygon,regular polygon
  sides=6,fill,text=white] (6gon2) {Model};
 \path coordinate[left=1em of b2] (aux2); 
 \draw[-stealth] (6gon2.east) -| (aux2) |- (b1.east) (aux2) -- (b2);
 \draw[-stealth] (pf) -- (b1);
```

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shapes.misc,shapes.multipart,intersections}
\newsavebox\boxA
\newsavebox\boxB
\newsavebox\boxC
\newsavebox\boxD
\newsavebox\boxE
\tikzset{2box/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw,minimum
width=#1},2box/.default=8em,
every picture/.append style={font=\sffamily,
every text node part/.style={align=center},
every pin edge/.style={-stealth}},
chess/.style={minimum size=#1,draw,fill=gray!20,path picture={
\foreach \XX in {0,...,4}
{\ifnum\XX>0
\draw ($(path picture bounding box.north west)+\XX*(#1/5,0)$) 
-- ($(path picture bounding box.south west)+\XX*(#1/5,0)$)
($(path picture bounding box.north west)+\XX*(0,-#1/5)$) 
-- ($(path picture bounding box.north east)+\XX*(0,-#1/5)$);
\fi
\draw[fill=blue!50] ($(path picture bounding box.north west)+\XX*(#1/5,-#1/5)$)
rectangle ++(#1/5,-#1/5); }
}},chess/.default=1.5cm,rr/.style={rounded rectangle,draw,align=center},
2ell/.style={ellipse split,draw}}
\sbox\boxA{\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={grow'=0,edge={-stealth},l sep=4em}
[{Data\nodepart{two}Labels},2box=10em
 [{Training Data\nodepart{two}Training  Labels},2box,fill=gray!20]
 [{Test Data\nodepart{two}Test Labels},2box=6em,fill=green!20]
]
\end{forest}}
\sbox\boxB{\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={grow'=0,edge={-stealth},l sep=3em,s sep=0.3em,
where level=1{rr,anchor=center,l sep+=4em}{},
where level=2{chess,no edge,pin={[node font=\small]right:Performance}}{},
}
[{Training Data\nodepart{two}Training  Labels},2box,fill=gray!20,anchor=text
split east
 [Hyperparameters\\ value
  [{},alias=ml31]
  ]
 [Hyperparameters\\ value,alias=ml22
  [{},alias=ml32]
  ]
 [Hyperparameters\\ value
  [{},alias=ml33]
 ]
]
\path let \p1=($(ml31.north)-(ml33.south)$) in (ml22) -- (ml32) 
    node[name path=elli,midway,ellipse,draw,node font=\bfseries,align=center,
    minimum height=\y1,inner xsep=-1ex]{Learning\\
    Algorithm};
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\path[name path=l\X] (ml3\X.west-|ml22.east) -- (ml3\X.west);
\path[name intersections={of=elli and l\X,sort by=l\X}]
\ifnum\X=1
(ml3\X.west-|ml22.east) edge[-stealth] (intersection-2)
(intersection-1) edge[-stealth] (ml3\X.west)
\else
(ml3\X.west-|ml22.east) edge[-stealth] (intersection-1)
(intersection-2) edge[-stealth] (ml3\X.west)
\fi;}   
\end{forest}}
\sbox\boxC{\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=0,edge={-stealth},l sep=4em}
[{Training Data\nodepart{two}Training  Labels},2box,fill=gray!20,anchor=text
split east
 [{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
 \textbf{Best}\\ hyperparameters\\ values\\[-0.3ex]~
\end{tabular}\nodepart{lower}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}~\\[-0.3ex]\textbf{Learning} \\\textbf{Algorithm}\end{tabular}},
 2ell,anchor=center,inner ysep=-1.8ex
  [Model,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,fill,text=white,anchor=center]
 ] 
]
\end{forest}}
\sbox\boxD{\begin{forest}
        for tree={grow'=0,edge={-stealth},l sep=4em}
        [{Data\nodepart{two}  Labels},2box,fill=white,anchor=text
        split east
        [{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
                \textbf{Best}\\ hyperparameters\\ values\\[-0.3ex]~
            \end{tabular}\nodepart{lower}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}~\\[-0.3ex]\textbf{Learning} \\\textbf{Algorithm}\end{tabular}},
        2ell,anchor=center,inner ysep=-1.8ex
        [Final \\ Model,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,fill,text=white,anchor=center]
        ] 
        ]
\end{forest}}
\newcommand{\BC}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(X.base)}]
\node[circle,fill,text=white,minimum size=1.3em,#1](X){#2};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{cp{1em}l}
\BC{1} & & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\boxA}}}\\[4em]
\BC{2} & & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\boxB}}}\\[6em]
\BC{3} & & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\boxC}}}\\[5em]
\BC{4} & & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\boxC}}}\\[5em]
\BC{5} & & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\boxD}}}\\
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed just a quick copy and paste (and some marginal adjustments).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric,shapes.misc,shapes.multipart,intersections}
\foreach \X in {A,...,E}
{\expandafter\newsavebox\csname box\X\endcsname}
\tikzset{gbox/.style={draw,minimum size=1.2em,fill=green!50},
 2box/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw,minimum
width=#1},2box/.default=8em,
every picture/.append style={font=\sffamily,
every text node part/.style={align=center},
every pin edge/.style={-stealth}},
chess/.style={minimum size=#1,draw,fill=gray!20,path picture={
\foreach \XX in {0,...,4}
{\ifnum\XX>0
\draw ($(path picture bounding box.north west)+\XX*(#1/5,0)$) 
-- ($(path picture bounding box.south west)+\XX*(#1/5,0)$)
($(path picture bounding box.north west)+\XX*(0,-#1/5)$) 
-- ($(path picture bounding box.north east)+\XX*(0,-#1/5)$);
\fi
\draw[fill=blue!50] ($(path picture bounding box.north west)+\XX*(#1/5,-#1/5)$)
rectangle ++(#1/5,-#1/5); }
}},chess/.default=1.5cm,rr/.style={rounded rectangle,draw,align=center},
2ell/.style={ellipse split,draw}}
\sbox\boxA{\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={grow'=0,edge={-stealth},l sep=4em}
[{Data\nodepart{two}Labels},2box=10em
 [{Training Data\nodepart{two}Training  Labels},2box,fill=gray!20]
 [{Test Data\nodepart{two}Test Labels},2box=6em,fill=green!20]
]
\end{forest}}
\sbox\boxB{\begin{forest}
forked edges,
for tree={grow'=0,edge={-stealth},l sep=3em,s sep=0.3em,
where level=1{rr,anchor=center,l sep+=4em}{},
where level=2{chess,no edge,pin={[node font=\small]right:Performance}}{},
}
[{Training Data\nodepart{two}Training  Labels},2box,fill=gray!20,anchor=text
split east
 [Hyperparameters\\ value
  [{},alias=ml31]
  ]
 [Hyperparameters\\ value,alias=ml22
  [{},alias=ml32]
  ]
 [Hyperparameters\\ value
  [{},alias=ml33]
 ]
]
\path let \p1=($(ml31.north)-(ml33.south)$) in (ml22) -- (ml32) 
    node[name path=elli,midway,ellipse,draw,node font=\bfseries,align=center,
    minimum height=\y1,inner xsep=-1ex]{Learning\\
    Algorithm};
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\path[name path=l\X] (ml3\X.west-|ml22.east) -- (ml3\X.west);
\path[name intersections={of=elli and l\X,sort by=l\X}]
\ifnum\X=1
(ml3\X.west-|ml22.east) edge[-stealth] (intersection-2)
(intersection-1) edge[-stealth] (ml3\X.west)
\else
(ml3\X.west-|ml22.east) edge[-stealth] (intersection-1)
(intersection-2) edge[-stealth] (ml3\X.west)
\fi;}   
\end{forest}}
\sbox\boxC{\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=0,edge={-stealth},l sep=4em}
[{Training Data\nodepart{two}Training  Labels},2box,fill=gray!20,anchor=text
split east
 [{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
 \textbf{Best}\\ hyperparameters\\ values\\[-0.3ex]~
\end{tabular}\nodepart{lower}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}~\\[-0.3ex]\textbf{Learning} \\\textbf{Algorithm}\end{tabular}},
 2ell,anchor=center,inner ysep=-1.8ex
  [Model,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,fill,text=white,anchor=center]
 ] 
]
\end{forest}}

\sbox\boxD{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[gbox](b1){Validation\\ Fold Data};
 \node[right=4em of b1,gbox,yshift=-0.5ex] (b2){Prediction};
 \node[below=4em of b2,gbox] (b3){Validation\\ Fold Labels};
 \path (b2) -- (b3) coordinate[midway,right=4em] (aux)
  node[right=2em of aux] (PF) {Performance};
 \draw[-stealth] (b2.east) -| (aux) |- (b3.east) (aux) -- (PF);
 \node[below=0.1em of b1,regular polygon,regular polygon
  sides=6,fill,text=white] (6gon2) {Model};
 \path coordinate[left=1em of b2] (aux2); 
 \draw[-stealth] (6gon2.east) -| (aux2) |- (b1.east) (aux2) -- (b2);
\end{tikzpicture}} 
\sbox\boxE{\begin{forest}
        for tree={grow'=0,edge={-stealth},l sep=4em}
        [{Data\nodepart{two}  Labels},2box=9em,fill=white,anchor=text
        split east
        [{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
                \textbf{Best}\\ hyperparameters\\ values\\[-0.3ex]~
            \end{tabular}\nodepart{lower}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}~\\[-0.3ex]\textbf{Learning} \\\textbf{Algorithm}\end{tabular}},
        2ell,anchor=center,inner ysep=-1.8ex
        [Final \\ Model,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,fill,text=white,anchor=center]
        ] 
        ]
\end{forest}}
\newcommand{\BC}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(X.base)}]
\node[circle,fill,text=white,minimum size=1.3em,#1](X){#2};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{cp{1em}l}
\BC{1} & & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\boxA}}}\\[4em]
\BC{2} & & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\boxB}}}\\[6em]
\BC{3} & & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\boxC}}}\\[5em]
\BC{4} & & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\boxD}}}\\[5em]
\BC{5} & & \vcenter{\hbox{\usebox{\boxE}}}\\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It’s so good to have you back ;)

Comment: I tried to make it a `standalone` document but it does not work. How can I do that?

Comment: @Delan Just replace `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}` by `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}`.